# Calculating the date from day-number?

Tags: c++

How would one go about calculating a date from a day-number in C++? I don't require you to write the whole code, I just can't figure out the maths to calculate the month and the day-of-month!

Example:

```
input: 1
output: 01/01/2012

input: 10
output: 01/10/2012

input: 365
output: 12/31/2012
```

It would always use the current year, if they exceeded 365, I would return 0. There is no need for a leap-year detection.

Comment: Without a library function, I've never found a way to do this without a lookup table. 12 entries, each with # of days in the year up *to* that month. Then just get the month, look it up and add the day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a date calc library as e.g. the fine [Boost Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time) library with which this becomes

```
using namespace boost::gregorian;
date d(2012,Jan,1);                     // or one of the other constructors
date d2 = d + days(365);                // or your other offsets
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not even very hard with the standard library.  Forgive me if I write C++ code like a C programmer (the C++ `<ctime>` has no reentrant `gmtime` function):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    tm t;
    int daynum = 10;

    time_t now = time(NULL);
    gmtime_r(&now, &t);
    t.tm_sec = 0;
    t.tm_min = 0;
    t.tm_hour = 0;
    t.tm_mday = 1;
    t.tm_mon = 1;
    time_t ref = mktime(&t);
    time_t day = ref + (daynum - 1) * 86400;
    gmtime_r(&day, &t);
    std::printf("%02d/%02d/%04d\n", t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday, 1900 + t.tm_year);

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry, I don't know a sane way to do this *without* leap-year detection.

Answer (score 1):

A simple **snippet** from a program, assuming 365 days in a year:

```
int input, day, month = 0, months[13] = {0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365};

while (input > 365) {
    // Parse the input to be less than or equal to 365
    input -= 365;
}

while (months[month] < input) {
    // Figure out the correct month.
    month++;
}

// Get the day thanks to the months array
day = input - months[month - 1];
```